# How to start Application main activity with Animation

Tags: android

how can i show my object on activity by Translate Animation  when onCreate() method called??

i called this method after setContentView() on my onCreate() but doesn't work!
help me please and don't give me negativ point please!

```
 public void startAnimation(){
    LinearLayout header=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_header);
    LinearLayout onOff=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_onoff);
    LinearLayout social=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.social_layer);
    LinearLayout netwo=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.network_layer);
    Animation in_1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.in_1);
    Animation in_2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.in_2);
    Animation in_3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.in_3);
    Animation in_4=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.in_4);
    header.startAnimation(in_1);
    onOff.startAnimation(in_2);
    social.startAnimation(in_3);
    netwo.startAnimation(in_4);
}
```

Comment: Instead of from onCreate(), can you call this method from the activity's onResume() method ?

Comment: but in firstof all oncreate method run!!i want to show my object by animation in ferst of opening app (Sorry for bad engish) @Ashwin

Comment: What do you mean by first time when the user opened app, do you mean it should just open for the very first time the user installed your app and opened it and even if the user killed the app and reopened it, it should not appear ?

Comment: every time user reopened it @Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

in your code nothing its wrong please showme the xml of your animation and showme xml of your activity

note: move your code from method to onCreate()

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:fromYDelta="2000"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="300"


    >
</translate>